# nodejs multer upload fails on heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, multer

i deployed both my nodejs and react apps on heroku, however multer upload works on `localhost` but not in production, it gives error `Access to fetch has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` which is not true

```
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use("/files", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/files")));


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "public/files");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array("file");

app.post("/upload", function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    } else if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
    return res.status(200).send("files have been uploaded successfully");
  });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, () => {
  console.log("listening at port 8000");
});
```

through react request is sent to `/upload` with required files:

```
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);


  const handleCareer= ()=>{
      const data = new FormData();
      const pdf = `${Date.now()}${files[0]?.name}`;
      const image = `${Date.now()}${files[1]?.name}`;

      for (let x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
        data.append("file", files[x]);
      }

      career.resume = pdf;
      career.resumeImage = image;
      await fetch("https://shoushapi.herokuapp.com/upload", {
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      });
}

return (
   <form>
    ...

          <div className="row">
            <label htmlFor="resumeFile" className="downloadImg">
              <AddAPhotoIcon className="postIcon" />
              <span>Upload resume</span>
            </label>

            <input
              type="file"
              accept="application/pdf,application/msword"
              id="resumeFile"
              name="file"
              className="upload"
              onChange={(e) => setFiles([...files, e.target.files[0]])}
            ></input>
          </div>

          <div className="row">
            <label htmlFor="resumeImage" className="downloadImg">
              <AddAPhotoIcon className="postIcon" />
              <span>Upload resume image</span>
            </label>

            <input
              type="file"
              accept=".png,.jpeg,.jpg"
              id="resumeImage"
              className="upload"
              onChange={(e) => setFiles([...files, e.target.files[0]])}
              name="image"
            ></input>
          </div>

          <div className="row">
            <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={handleCareer}>
              Request
            </button>
          </div>
   </form>
```

the code works fine in development mode, if i change `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `http://localhost:8000` and change fetch url to `http://localhost:8000/upload`, files will be uploaded successfully through running locally, what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow origin for your front-end website url not for your API endpoint,
you can set that in the cors method without using headers:

```
cors({ origin: "your front-end" })
```

or you can remove allow origin header and keep the cors method empty like this: `app.use(cors())`, and in that case you will allow all websites to use your api.

I think the reason why you still can accept requests from your localhost front end to your localhost api, is because, the both of them are hosted with the same domain and both of them are using the same proxy.

Comment: none of that worked, both gives ```Access to fetch at 'https://shoushapi.herokuapp.com/upload' from origin 'https://shoushclient.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource```

Comment: btw, every other route works fine, only ```/upload``` gives that error